# How do I configure Prometheus for aggregated metrics?

Tags: alerts, metrics, prometheus

I have five related questions around the configuration of Prometheus for aggregated metric reception.

There are some invariants in my system:

- Python server code that needs to be instrumented
- Prometheus service that needs to get aggregated metrics for alerts

Everything in the middle is currently being designed. I've done some reading on how this is supposed to work but have gone quite in circles.

[Push Gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) expressly [does not support](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#non-goals) aggregation:

> The Pushgateway is explicitly not an *aggregator or distributed counter* but rather a metrics cache. It does not have [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd)-like semantics. The metrics pushed are exactly the same as you would present for scraping in a permanently running program. If you need distributed counting, you could either use the actual statsd in combination with the [Prometheus statsd exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter), or have a look at [Weavework's aggregation gateway](https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway).

But then **(1)** why would its official [Python client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) support [`Histogram`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#histogram), which

> allows for aggregatable calculation of quantiles

?

If I go the `statsd` route, then [`statsd_exporter`](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter) says that

> Since the StatsD exporter uses the same line protocol as StatsD itself, you can also configure your applications to send StatsD metrics directly to the exporter. In that case, you don't need to run a StatsD server anymore.

**(2)** Does this mean that Prometheus *does* in fact support aggregation in `statsd_exporter` alone?

I would want to use the most popular Python bindings for `statsd`, simply called [`statsd`](https://pypi.org/project/statsd) in pypi. But it claims that

> [statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) is a friendly front-end to [Graphite](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/). This is a Python client for the statsd daemon.

**(3)** If I only used `statsd_exporter`, could I get away with skipping the Graphite dependency?

Finally: the docs for `statsd_exporter` also say that

> We recommend this only as an intermediate solution and recommend switching to [native Prometheus instrumentation](http://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) in the long term.

The "native Prometheus implementation" link for Python brings me back to `prometheus_client`, but it immediately seems like that's *not a client* - it's [tightly coupled to a server implementation](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#three-step-demo), as seen here:

> Metrics are usually exposed over HTTP, to be read by the Prometheus server.
>
> The easiest way to do this is via `start_http_server`, which will start a HTTP server in a daemon thread on the given port.

**(4)** Does that mean that the "native" instrumentation requires that you attach an instrumentation *server* to code that gets queried by Prometheus? **(5)** If this were to use `Histogram`, would it support aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

There exists one Prometheus gateway that handles aggregation: https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway

But note that gauge aggregation is currently not implemented, https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway/issues/8